# Python indented block error

Tags: python

I had an indented block error on line 4:

```
from SimPy.Simulation import *
from random import uniform
class Car(Process):
def init(self,id):
Process.init(self)
self.id=id
def carDriving(self,driveTime):
```

...

What might be causing it?

Comment: More a case of what's right. Read a tutorial http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Comment: I wanted to edit this question to fix "intended" to "indented" but I ended up with variations of "Indented block error: my code has an indented block error" and that really isn't much of an improvement.

Comment: I also found that removing the tag from the title caused a collision with an existing thread with the exact same name. This question is of extremely dubious value.

Answer (score 4):

You have to indent classes and functions:

```
from SimPy.Simulation import *
from random import uniform

class Car(Process):
    def __init__(self, id):
        Process.init(self)
        self.id = id

    def carDriving(self, driveTime):
        # do something here
        pass
```

Comment: I think it would be `__init__` and  Process.init(self) does not look correct either